# Remove spaces around hyphen in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I have the next strings:

'foo-bar'

'foo - bar'

'foo -bar'

'foo- bar'

'foo- bar-baz'

'foo - bar -baz'

'foo- bar baz'

etc.

What is the best way in ruby to make them all without spaces around hyphens? 
Spaces between words without hyphens should stay.

Example of expected result:
'foo-bar'
'foo-bar-baz'
'foo-bar baz'

Comment: `"foo-bar -baz - blerp blorp".gsub(/\s+(?=-)|(?<=-)\s+/, &:strip) #⇒ "foo-bar-baz-blerp blorp"`.

Comment: All of the answers use some variant of `str.gsub(/\s*-\s*/, '-')`, but suppose `str = "my - oh-\n my"`.   Then `str.gsub(/\s*-\s*/, '-') #=> "my-oh-my"`, which is incorrect. If you wish to remove spaces around hyphens remove spaces, not whitespaces: `str.gsub(/ *- */, '-') #=> "my-oh-\n my"`.

Answer (score 4):

The quick and effective way is with a regular expression:

```
"foo-bar -baz - blerp blorp".gsub(/\s*-\s*/, "-")
=> "foo-bar-baz-blerp blorp"
```

The `\s*` means "zero or more whitespace characters". Note that this will match tabs as well as spaces. If you only want to match spaces, use `[ ]*` instead.

Comment: Why `/[ ]*/` and not `/ */`? I'd understand if you were using `/x`... Readability?

Comment: Yes, readability. It's a habit I got into as I often use `/x` to separate complex parts of a regex and even add comments if helpful. `[ ]` feels more explicit and obvious, which is usually my preference.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions. I believe you regular expression should eq to something like this:

```
regex = /\s*-\s*/

test_strings = ["foo-bar baz", "foo - bar baz", "foo -bar"]

test_strings.map do |test_string|
  test_string.gsub(regex, "-")
end
# => ["foo-bar baz", "foo-bar baz", "foo-bar"]
```

A bonus tip, here is a great app to construct your regular expressions: https://rubular.com/

Answer (score 2):

More universal variant (without repeating delimiter):

```
"foo-bar -baz - blerp blorp".gsub(/\s*-\s*/) { |part| part.strip }
 => "foo-bar-baz-blerp blorp"
```

Comment: `"foo-bar -baz - blerp blorp".gsub(/\s*-\s*/, &:strip)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution without regex, you could simply split the string at every `'-'`, strip the substrings and join them again:

```
"foo - bar -baz".split('-').map(&:strip).join('-')
# => "foo-bar-baz"
```

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, you may need to try `\s*-\s*` istead of `/\s*-\s*/`.

i.e. for Python, only this worked:

```
import re

print(re.sub('\s*-\s*', '-', 'd - a co- ca ce -la '))  # "d-a co-ca ce-la "
```

While this is not working:

```
print(re.sub('/\s*-\s*/', '-', 'd - a co- ca ce -la '))  # "d - a co- ca ce -la "
```